# linux mint xrdp xfce : X server already running on display :10.0

Tags: linuxmint, xrdp

I'm on Linux Mint 21, xfce version.

I setup xrdp with basic command :

```
apt install xrdp
```

I have an `/etc/xrdp/startvm.sh` configuration like that :

```
#/bin/sh
startxfce4 >> ~/xrdp.log
```

When I connect with an RDP client, I got the `xrdp Just Connecting login` screen.

I choose `Xorg`, then entre my username and password. But when I submit the login form, the connection terminate unexpectedly.

There is nothing particular in the `/var/log/xrdp.log` or `/var/log/xrdp-ses.log`

The `~/xrdp.log` indicates :

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :10.0
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :10.0
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :10.0
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :10.0
...
```

The `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log` indicates :

```
20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username myuser, ip x.x.x.x:31947 - socket: 12
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Starting session: session_pid 23543, display :10.0, width 1920, height 1080, bpp 24, client ip x.x.x.x:31947 - socket: 12, user name myuser
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] [session start] (display 10): calling auth_start_session from pid 23543
[20220821-23:43:13] [ERROR] sesman_data_in: scp_process_msg failed
[20220821-23:43:13] [ERROR] sesman_main_loop: trans_check_wait_objs failed, removing trans
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Starting X server on display 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log  
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Session started successfully for user myuser on display 10
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Found X server running at /tmp/.X11-unix/X10
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 10: /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh
[20220821-23:43:13] [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 23544) exits to end the session
[20220821-23:43:14] [WARN ] Window manager (pid 23544, display 10) exited with non-zero exit code 139 and signal 0. This could indicate a window manager config problem
[20220821-23:43:14] [WARN ] Window manager (pid 23544, display 10) exited quickly (1 secs). This could indicate a window manager config problem
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] Calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 23543
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] Terminating X server (pid 23545) on display 10
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] Terminating the xrdp channel server (pid 23553) on display 10
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] X server on display 10 (pid 23545) returned exit code 0 and signal number 0
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] xrdp channel server for display 10 (pid 23553) exit code 0 and signal number 0
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] cleanup_sockets:
[20220821-23:43:14] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username myuser, display :10.0, session_pid 23543, ip x.x.x.x:31947 - socket: 12
```

How to further debug ?

Answer (score 0):

My user was already connected trough the Proxmox VNC, so I have to disconnect the user, and then the session works with an other RDP client